# Access to individual users on azure resources

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azureservicebus

We can connect to azure resources like storage accounts, azure sql server, service bus,message bus etc using access key. Can we give access on these resources to individual users? Is there a way users can connect using their AD account and restrict access e.g, readonly, read/write etc.

Comment: Have you tried [Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access but there are lot of limitations on read only or write only stuff. Check out a post on https://serverfault.com/questions/872423/azure-assign-user-read-download-access-to-blobs-in-storage-account and that should answer your question.